# What does "blow by a cop" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I came across it in the fifth episode of the fourth season of *Rick and Morty*. The context is Rick and Morty go back in time to give the snakes a book to help then invent time travel so that they destroy themselves, which in turn would allow Rick and Morty to get out of the situation they had created.

> Morty: Jesus Christ, Rick, it's pandemonium out there! This is worse
> than when we left. Rick, look, Summer!
>
> Summer: Nobody chokes me without consent.
>
> Mory: Y-You just made things worse, Rick.
>
> Rick: Trust me, Morty. We helped them press on the gas pedal. We just
> got to wait for them to **blow by a cop**.

Comment: It means they're going to go super fast by a cop...

Comment: You really need to be careful using this kind of text as a "learning aid". There will be an awful lot of usages in *Rick and Morty* that are completely meaningless to the average native Anglophone. And in this particular case, you'd be wasting brain cells committing to memory the usage ***to blow by X = to pass X moving at speed***. You might *never* meet that usage again even if you spend the rest of your life watching English-language TV. It's only really got meaning ***in context***.

Comment: FumbleFingers: You've made a good point. Still whenever I meet new language there I am curious to know its meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, Rick is stating that by "press(ing) on the gas pedal", they are accelerating, and hence, going at a greater speed. The word "blow" simply means "to pass by" or "been seen by" a police officer, and then, hopefully get pulled over for exceeding the speed limit.

Comment: to blow past or by someone is the idiom.